# Could not find `collections` in `anchor_lang` 0.2.9

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang

I want to `use anchor_lang::collections::BTreeMap;` since `BTreeMap` is apparently a hashmap that works on-chain. However this fails to import with:

```
could not find `collections` in `anchor_lang`
```

My dependencies include `anchor-lang`. Originally I thought something had changed in a new anchor-lang release but I can't fund anything about this on the internet.

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.29.0", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
```

Answer (score 2):

This was a GitHub copilot hallucination. From copilot:

> You need to use the BTreeMap from the anchor_lang::collections module, not the standard library.

This is not correct and there is no `anchor_lang::collections` module. Just use:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
```